# PDF, выдача веб страницой

Tags: pdf

Появился такой вопрос, ответ на который найти не получилось. **При вставке PDF файла в веб страницу, поисковая машина индексирует, а потом выдает и PDF и страницу.** Каким образом можно "слить" их вместе, дабы юзер попал именно на страницу сайта, а не чисто PDF документ?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно скрыть файлы pdf-файлы от поисковиков. Это можно сделать прописав в файле .htaccess или httpd.conf:

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Можно прописать в файле robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *.pdf
```

Так же можно на странице со ссылкой на сам файл, в ссылке прописать rel="nofollow"

```
<a href="file.pdf" rel="nofollow">Ваш PDF</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но в таком случае ведь сам текст из PDF (если он распознан), не будет проиндексирован...? Значит выдача будет происходить только по названию PDF и тегам title+description?
Если это так, есть ли вариант дать возможность поисковику индексировать текст из PDF, но выдавать результат веб страницой, без чистого PDF?

Comment: не думаю что это возможно.

Comment: А есть ли возможность делать редирект? С допустим 1.pdf > 1.php, в одной и той же папке.

Comment: Да, редирект можно сделать.

Comment: Но как тогда будет поисковый бот индексировать pdf?

Comment: Не подумала об этом... Выходит замкнутый круг ):
А "HTTP-заголовок rel=canonical" не сможет помочь в этом вопросе?  Пусть даже PDF'ы и попадают в поиск, но что бы приоритет ниже был, чем у обычных страниц?
Спасибо (:

Comment: Все верно, rel="canonical" должен помочь в этом плане.